# Склонение собирательных существительных

Tags: морфология

Подскажите, в каком падеже употреблять существительное в предложении: "Купи орешки" или "Купи орешков"? Кажется, в родительном падеже собирательное существительное употребляется, когда есть уточнение количества: "Купи килограмм орешков". А если без уточнения?

Comment: купи что - орехи, купи чего - орехов. И так и так можно. Орехи - понятие, орехов - множественное от орех в косвенном падеже. Получил на орехи, получил орехов - понятие может мигрировать в другие части речи, наречие например тут, а форма сохраняется и не меняется. На, вот, на орехов - возьми орехи, на, вот, на орехи - звучит двусмысленно и может произносится слитно с предлогом.